# Update mutiple rows in table using Realm in Android

Tags: android, database, realm

I am using **Realm** to store my values in local database.

My requirement is that i need to change one field `status=1` based on some condition.

I have tried following method to accomplish this task. And it is working fine.

```
   RealmResults<NotificationOrder> notificationOrders=realm
            .where(NotificationOrder.class)
            .equalTo(RealmConstants.TBL_NOTIFICATION_ORDER.property_id,ConstantMethod.getPreference(getActivity(),UserDefault.kPropertyId))
            .equalTo(RealmConstants.TBL_NOTIFICATION_ORDER.status,0)
            .findAll();

    for (NotificationOrder order:notificationOrders) {
        realm.beginTransaction();
        order.setStatus(1);
        realm.commitTransaction();
    }
```

Now there may be 1000 of such rows in my local db and using for loop to update single row doesn't seem proper way.

So my question :*Is there any way like `MYSQL` Update Queries in Realm by which we can update all rows having status=0 by single statement instead of updating single row one by one ?*

Thanks.

Comment: Currently no, you would need to update all objects individually. There is an issue tracking it here: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/762

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I know right, the objects in the transaction ought to be managed, so

```
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
       RealmResults<NotificationOrder> notificationOrders = realm
            .where(NotificationOrder.class)
            .equalTo(RealmConstants.TBL_NOTIFICATION_ORDER.property_id,ConstantMethod.getPreference(getActivity(),UserDefault.kPropertyId))
            .equalTo(RealmConstants.TBL_NOTIFICATION_ORDER.status,0)
            .findAll();
        for(NotificationOrder order : notificationOrders) {
            order.setStatus(1);
        }
    }
});
```

Should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can do, bulk update by `setValue` method like this:

```
realm.where(NotificationOrder.class)
.equalTo(RealmConstants.TBL_NOTIFICATION_ORDER.property_id,ConstantMethod.getPreference(getActivity(),UserDefault.kPropertyId))
            .equalTo(RealmConstants.TBL_NOTIFICATION_ORDER.status,0)
            .findAll()
            .setValue(RealmConstants.REALM_FIELD_NAME,value); // 1st parameter is field name, 2nd is value
```